Reference request: given a set of integers, find a subset whose product is square
I'm looking for a reference related to this quote from the Wikipedia article on Quadratic Sieve, which discusses a method for finding a subset of integers whose product is square by determining the null space of a certain matrix over the field of two elements $\mathbb{F}_2$.
I'm writing a paper that uses this technique, and I'm having trouble finding good references to cite that discuss this method explicitly.
(I don't particularly care about the quadratic sieve setup, I'm just interested in the linear algebra technique for finding a subset of integers whose product is square.)

So the problem has now been reduced to: given a set of integers, find a subset whose product is a square. By the fundamental theorem of arithmetic, any positive integer can be written uniquely as a product of prime powers. We do this in a vector format; for example, the prime-power factorization of $504$ is $2^33^25^07^1$, it is therefore represented by the exponent vector $(3,2,0,1)$. Multiplying two integers then corresponds to adding their exponent vectors. A number is a square when its exponent vector is even in every coordinate. For example, the vectors $(3,2,0,1) + (1,0,0,1) = (4,2,0,2)$, so $(504)(14)$ is a square. Searching for a square requires knowledge only of the parity of the numbers in the vectors, so it is sufficient to compute these vectors mod $2$: $(1,0,0,1) + (1,0,0,1) = (0,0,0,0)$. So given a set of $(0,1)$-vectors, we need to find a subset which adds to the zero vector mod $2$.
This is a linear algebra problem since the ring $\displaystyle \mathbb {Z} /2\mathbb {Z}$ can be regarded as the Galois field of order $2$, that is we can divide by all non-zero numbers (there is only one, namely $1$) when calculating modulo $2$. It is a theorem of linear algebra that with more vectors than each vector has entries, a linear dependency always exists. It can be found by Gaussian elimination.


Are you familiar with how to compute the nullspace of a matrix using row reduced echelon form? This is the same theorem but over $\mathbb{F}_2$.

@QiaochuYuan. I'm familiar with the technique and I know how to implement it both by hand with RREF and in code—I'm just looking for some references to cite.

What is the audience of your paper?

@davidlowryduda—like a MAA Mathematics Magazine kind of vibe.

Carl Pomerance writes in a December 1996 Notices article, "A Tale of Two Sieves":

A systematic strategy for finding a subsequence of a given sequence with product a square was found by John Brillhart and Michael Morrison, and, surprisingly, it is at heart only linear algebra (see [16]). Every positive integer $m$ has an exponent vector $v(m)$ that is based on the prime factorization of $m$. Let $p_i$ denote the $i$-th
prime, and say $m = \prod p_i^{v_i}$. (The product is over
all primes, but only finitely many of the exponents vi are nonzero.) Then $v(m)$ is the vector
$(v_1, v_2, \dots)$. [...]

This is just what I was looking for—a really nice explanation by Pomerance, and a citation to the original idea (Brillhart and Morrison).
